# JavaCC: treat white space like <OR>

Tags: parsing, grammar, javacc

I'm trying to build a simple grammar for Search Engine query.
I've got this so far -

```
options {
  STATIC=false;
  MULTI=true;
  VISITOR=true;
}

PARSER_BEGIN(SearchParser)
package com.syncplicity.searchservice.infrastructure.parser;
public class SearchParser {}
PARSER_END(SearchParser)

SKIP :
{
  " "
| "\t"
| "\n"
| "\r"
}

<*> TOKEN : {
  <#_TERM_CHAR:       ~[ " ", "\t", "\n", "\r", "!", "(", ")", "\"", "\\", "/" ] >
| <#_QUOTED_CHAR:     ~["\""] >
| <#_WHITESPACE:      ( " " | "\t" | "\n" | "\r" | "\u3000") >
}

TOKEN :
{
  <AND:              "AND">
| <OR:               "OR">
| <NOT:              ("NOT" | "!")>
| <LBRACKET:         "(">
| <RBRACKET:         ")">
| <TERM:             (<_TERM_CHAR>)+ >
| <QUOTED:           "\"" (<_QUOTED_CHAR>)+ "\"">
}

/** Main production. */

ASTQuery query() #Query: {}
{
  subQuery()
  ( <AND> subQuery() #LogicalAnd
  | <OR> subQuery() #LogicalOr
  | <NOT> subQuery() #LogicalNot
  )*
  {
    return jjtThis;
  }
}

void subQuery() #void: {}
{
  <LBRACKET> query() <RBRACKET> | term() | quoted()
}

void term() #Term:
{
  Token t;
}
{
  (
    t=<TERM>
  )
  {
    jjtThis.value = t.image;
  }
}

void quoted() #Quoted:
{
  Token t;
}
{
  (
    t=<QUOTED>
  )
  {
    jjtThis.value = t.image;
  }
}
```

Looks like it works as I wanted to, e.g it can handle `AND, OR, NOT/!`, single terms and quoted text.

However I can't force it to handle whitespaces between terms as `OR` operator. E.g `hello world` should be treated as `hello OR world`

I've tried all obvious solutions, like `<OR: ("OR" | " ")>`, removing `" "` from `SKIP`, etc. But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.  Suppose you actually do want to require that any missing ORs be replaced by at least one space.  Or to put it another way, if there is one or more white spaces where an OR would be permitted, then that white space is considered to be an OR.

As in my other solution, I'll treat NOT as a unary operator and give NOT precedence over AND and AND precedence over either sort of OR.

Change

```
SKIP : { " " | "\t" | "\n" | "\r" }
```

to

```
TOKEN : {<WS : " " | "\t" | "\n" | "\r" > }
```

Now use a grammar like this

```
query() --> query0() ows() <EOF>
query0() --> query1()
            ( LOOKAHEAD( ows() <OR> | ws() (<NOT> | <LBRACKET> | <TERM> | <QUOTED>) )
              ( ows() (<OR>)?
                query1()
            )* 
query1() --> query2() (LOOKAHEAD(ows() <AND>) ows() <AND> query2())*
query2() --> ows() (<NOT> query2() | subquery())
subquery() --> <LBRACKET> query0() ows() <RBRACKET> | <TERM> | <QUOTED>
ows() --> (<WS>)*
ws() --> (<WS>)+
```

Comment: Theodore, thank you very much for the solution. It works for me for most of the cases, but I have a problem with `NOT`. I've created a separate question for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46708697/javacc-and-jjtree-how-to-correctly-specify-nodes-in-the-grammar Please take a look if you have time

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you don't want whitespace treated as an OR, perhaps you want the OR keyword to be optional.  In that case you can use a grammar like this

```
query --> subquery (<AND> subquery | (<OR>)? subquery | <NOT> subquery)*
```

However this grammar treat NOT as an infix operator.  Also it doesn't reflect precedence. Usually NOT has precedence over AND and AND over OR. Also your main production should look for an EOF.  For that you can try

```
query --> query0 <EOF>
query0 --> query1 ((<OR>)? query1)*
query1 --> query2 (<AND> query2)*
query2 --> <NOT> query2 | subquery
subquery --> <LBRACKET> query0 <RBRACKET> | <TERM> | <QUOTED>
```

Comment: Actually I really want whitespace to be treated as <OR>. That's a common behavior of a search engines. When you type `hello world` - it'll search for both `hello` and `world` (unless the search phrase is quoted: `"hello world"` - but that case already works fine in my grammar)

Comment: I'd really appreciate if you have an idea how to implement `" "` like `OR`

Comment: So you would like that `"hello""world"` not be treated a `"hello" OR "world"`. And that `(hello)(world)` should not be treated as `(hello) OR (world)`. What about `("hello" )(world)`: should that be treated as `("hello"OR)(world)`? Probably not. Exactly what white space should be treated as an OR and what white space should not?

Comment: Edited to require an EOF.

Comment: @silent-box Theodore is right: `hello world` has two tokens, so does `hello        world`, whereas `helloword` and `"hello world"` have one. <OR> is optional..